# Is there a way to use Ubuntu Software Center without snaps?

Tags: software-center

Is there a way to use Ubuntu Software Center without snaps?

As it is I prefer no Ubuntu Software Center to having any snaps on my system, so I will live without Ubuntu Software Center unless there's a way to get it going without snaps.

I understand the Ubuntu Software Center used to work without requiring installed snaps, and I'm hoping there's still a way to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: @user535733 I'm sorry to hear that. I really liked Ubuntu and will be sad when I have to quit using it.

Comment: @KevinBerry The main benefit is being able to provide new versions of complex packages like Chromium for old Ubuntu releases. When Chromium is quick to drop support for old versions of libraries and you can’t install a new one systemwide in an LTS system, the distribution maintainers either need to implement such support themselves (very complex) or somehow provide a set of libraries for the package’s exclusive use (which is one of the main things snaps do).

Comment: Another similar question (mine):[How can I warn before installing snaps (Bionic, Focal)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1258653/178354)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can remove the snap store with the command

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
```

and install GNOME software center (if it is not already present) with the command

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends gnome-software
```

The `--no-install-recommends` ensures that snap plugins are not pulled as recommended packages.

Alternatively, you can also install the synaptic package manager, which is not an "app store", but provides a lot more functionality.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Comment: Hi Archisman! Thank you for the information. Synaptic is very nice. Unfortunately I can't install gnome-software because it also pulls in snap packages. Is there a way to install it so that it does not install any packages with "snap" in their names? (gir1.2-snapd-1 gnome-software-plugin-snap snapd)

Comment: @KevinBerry Check the updated answer

Comment: @KevinBerry You probably need to remove `gnome-software-plugin-snap` to avoid pulling snap packages by `gnome-software` - see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-store-from-ubuntu

Comment: @raj Thanks for the edit :-)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you! That worked without putting snaps on my system. Synaptic and Aptitude work nicely, but seeing the app icons is a nicer experience on my desktop environment. Best wishes! -Kevin

Comment: @KevinBerry Here is how to completely remove snaps with all their configs. https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/124466

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the Ubuntu Software Center, you may want to use the [GNOME Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software).
It is just like the Ubuntu Software Center, but it doesn't have Snap (or Flatpack) capabilities enabled by default.

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

If you want to enable Flatpak support in Gnome Software, execute the following:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

If you want to enable Snap support in Gnome Software, execute the following:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

If you *don't* add these two plugins, GNOME Software Center will just allow you to work with and mange deb packages, which is what you wanted.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer. I had to install gnome-software using --no-install-recommends as mentioned above. It works great without snaps, which is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Take, for example, VLC from the Ubuntu Software Center (which has both snap and deb packages available).

If you select VLC you will see a drop down on the header bar to the right. Select the down arrow and you will be provided with a list of VLC packages at the bottom of which (in this case) is the deb package.

[image]

This will mean that you will not have to delete the snap store, just select the deb package (if its available) and this will preserve matters for the future.

Comment: "@24601", thanks for taking the time to answer and explain this. I wish I could use the Ubuntu Software Center, but I haven't been able to find a way to install it without snaps, so I'm using the gnome software center now, which works nicely without snaps, but i had to install it as explained above using --no-install-recommends.

Comment: Is there any chance to do quite the opposite and exclude any DEBs in Snap Store to show only snaps? I use Synaptic Package Manager to manage debs, but would like to use Ubuntu Software to manage snaps only.